# Moving multiple clips on multiple Tracks in Audacity

Tags: windows, audacity

I made a Audacity Project with multiple tracks and multiple clips on these tracks. Now I want to add a pause at a point but I can not figure out how. Moving every clips on every tracks after this point manually would be really painful, is there an alternative? I am using the latest version of Audacity on Windows 10.

I hope this is not a wrong place for Audacity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok this is awkward, i struggled for days to find the answer so i decided to ask a question. I just found a way to solve it.

1. select the point you want to add a break.
2. drag across multiple tracks to select them. (did not you you could do that)
3. Shift-K to select everything after it.
4. drag to the right.

I am sorry for this but i think it may help someone.

Comment: Selecting multiple tracks with Ctrl shft or Ctrl does not work for me, I can only select one individual track at the time, weird. I did find this useful thanks. I have not figure out how to do it if tracks are not contiguous